# Looking for varied Matrix Size Projects

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.
I'm working on a project to accelerate heterogeneous autonomous robotics systems, mainly be sending large computations to work on the GPU. I've been struggling to try to find an established project that would be viable for this acceleration and I hope that someone might happen to know of such a project. The only real requirement would be it utilizes large and small matrices for computations like matrix multiplications.
Any pointing in the right direction would be really appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393892/looking-for-varied-matrix-size-projects/) by [Latman](https://answers.ros.org/users/92998/latman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could find any simulation of a robot using the nav stack, then tune the ekf_node settings. Look at the tutorial here:

https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html

If you scroll down, you'll see a datafile with odom0, imu0, etc. The more sensors, the larger the matrix. So you could make practically whatever matrix size you want.

(I suppose you could just repeat the same sensor over and over. imu0, imu1, imu2, etc...)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1